# Button cannot be covert to node, method list add(node) is not applicable

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm beginner at JavaFx. I tried to run basic things i.e button but i'm not able due to some compilation error i.e. Button cannot be covert to node, method list add(node) is not applicable [This is my simple code to run program in netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Bq1.png)

## Code

public class Hello extends Application{
     Button btn;

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
 primaryStage.setTitle("I'm beginner");

  btn=new Button("Click me");
  StackPane root=new StackPane();
  root.getChildren().add(btn);
  Scene scene=new Scene(root,350,400);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you used the button from 
`java.awt` package. Make sure that the `Button` is from `javafx.scene.control.Button` package.
I had similar problem once and wasted an hour on that stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check the imports. It should be `javafx.scene.control.Button` for Button and `javafx.scene.layout.StackPane` for StackPane.
Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/.

And http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

The method described in the tutorial combined with the new scene builder makes creating a javafx gui insanely easy.